# Additional log4j libraries besides the core

Tags: java, log4j

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any libraries that build on top of what comes with the core log4j library.

Comment: This question could be read many different ways. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @PeterLawrey In a few words, more Appenders, more tools in addition to the basics found on apache.org.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there a many libraries using `log4j` for their logging, but this would be to wide to  enumerate. However there are a couple of libraries which extend `log4j` in a certain manner:

- [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) is GUI based log viewer.
- [apache-log4j-zeroconf](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/zeroconf/download.html) is a addon for remote logging.
- Other logging frameworks like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) are able to use `log4j` as their backend.

Comment: i was already aware of those apache extras, i was after more appenders outside the apache community.

Comment: SLF4J does not really change anything if one uses LOG4J, its just a diff interface.

Answer (score 0):

New chainsaw developer snapshot with lots of new features: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Answer (score 0):

[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and log4j's new version [Log4j 2.0](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)